# Is Delphi Berlin Trial edition for MacOSX and iOS or just the starter edition?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am wondering if the Trial for Delphi Berlin includes iOS and MacOSX support.

I am a registered user of Delphi Berlin Starter, which does not compile code for MacOSX, so I am wondering if I download the Berlin Trial for 30 days, will it allow me to test compiling a MacOSX firemonkey app?  Then if it looks good I would buy Delphi pro/architect/enterprise in the future.

However if Delphi Berlin Trial edition is just the starter edition for 30 days then it is not so much use for me, as I already have Starter.

I could not find on the Embarcadero website which edition the trial download actually is for. Thought I would ask before I waste a few hundred megabytes of bandwidth downloading it only to find out it is "starter".

Answer (score 3):

The trial is the enterprise edition, but your use is limited for 30 days and the licence does not permit you to release software built with the trial. There are some limitations, notable no command line compilers and no library source code.

All platforms are available.

Comment: I am not so sure it is the Enterprise edition. I always thought it was the Architect edition.